# How not to infinite loop using setState in render REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to remove a row in my listview but when i get the data back it wont remove because the setstate is missing

```
 render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const deleterow = navigation.getParam('deleterow', '500');
    var newData = [...this.state.listViewData];
    newData.splice(deleterow,1)
    //this.setState({ listViewData: newData });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to do a `setState` from a component's `render` method.

As far as I understand, your aim is to modify the state's `listViewData` property that will be processed in your render method. Calling setState will trigger a `render()`, so, as you indicated in your code sample that you wish to modify this property inside your render method, you may assign it directly and process it below the assignment, provided the value is effective in `render` only:

```
render(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const deleterow = navigation.getParam('deleterow', '500');
    var newData = [...this.state.listViewData];
    newData.splice(deleterow,1)
    this.state.listViewData = newData;
    // use this.state.listViewData to populate the items of your view
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `componentwillreceiveprops` add a condition then do a setState.
You dont want to add setState in render method.

Comment: componentwillreceiveprops(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const deleterow = navigation.getParam('deleterow', '500');
    var newData = [...this.state.listViewData];
    newData.splice(deleterow,1)
    alert(deleterow)
    //this.setState({ listViewData: newData });
  }